# How to remove a group of characters from a string in python including shifting

Tags: python, string

For instance I have a string that needs a certain keyword removed from a string  so lets say may key word is`whatthemomooofun` and I want to delete the word `moo` from it, I have tried using the remove function but it only removes "moo" one time, but now my string is `whatthemoofun` and I can seem to remove it is there anyway I can do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `replace` in built function

```
def str_manipulate(word, key):
    while key in word:
       word = word.replace(key, '')
    return word
```

Comment: Best not to use built-in function names like `str()` for variables.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a while loop? You could loop through it until it doesn't find your keyword anymore then break out.

### Edit

Cause answer could be improved by an example, take a look at the general approach it deals with:

##### Example

```
s = 'whatthemomooofun'

while 'moo' in s:
    s= s.replace('moo','')

print(s)
```

##### Output

```
whatthefun
```

Answer (score 0):

```
original_string = "!(Hell@o)"
characters_to_remove = "!()@"

new_string = original_string
for character in characters_to_remove:
  new_string = new_string.replace(character, "")

print(new_string)
```

OUTPUT

```
Hello
```